# Choosing a random item from a tagged library

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-tagging

Gradding a random image causes the title, url (etc) attributes on the tag.rand_img to vanish, meaning I can't display anything more than the object name.

view.py:

```
def locations_gallery(request):
  queryset = Photo.objects.all()
  tags = Tag.objects.usage_for_queryset(queryset, counts=True)
  tags.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('count'), reverse=True)
  for tag in tags:
    image_tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag)
    tag.rand_img = TaggedItem.objects.get_union_by_model(Photo, image_tag).order_by('?')[:1]
  ctxt['tags'] = tags
  return render_to_response('locations_gallery.html', ctxt, RequestContext(request))
```

Template (simplified):

```
{% for tag in tags %}
{{ tag.name }}
<img src="{{ tag.rand_img.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
tag.rand_img = TaggedItem.objects.get_union_by_model(Photo, image_tag).order_by('?')[:1]
```

is returning a Queryset, not a model instance. The queryset doesn't have your custom methods, they exist only on the instance within that queryset.

Replace the `[:1]` with `[0]` to get the actual model instance (you'll need to catch `IndexError` in case there isn't a matching item).

Answer (score 1):

I'd first get the tags:

```
tags = Tag.objects.usage_for_queryset(queryset, counts=True)
tags.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('count'), reverse=True)
```

and then iterate through them and add the image as an extra field. Then you could do something like you've outlined in your template.

Comment: How do you add the image as an extra field?  That's the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: I think just doing a `tag.rand_img = img` should suffice.

Comment: tag.rand_img = tag causes the object to lose all its attributes like title, url etc

Comment: That's not right... [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends) says that you can add a field later on to the class. ...and it should be "... = img" , not "... = tag" :)

Comment: Thanks, thats just a typo.  I think the line TaggedItem.objects.get_union_by_model(Photo, image_tag).order_by('?')[:1] is removing the extra attributes I need.  I'll update the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes like that, Python will allow it but then you are no longer working on a `QuerySet`.

Try this:

```
def get_rand_img(tag):
   return TaggedItem.objects.get_union_by_model(Photo, tag).order_by('?')[:1]

display_tags = [(Tag.objects.get(name=tag),
                 get_rand_img(Tag.objects.get(name=tag))) for tag in tags]
ctxt['tags'] = display_tags
```

Then in your view

```
{% for tag, rand_img in tags %}
   {{ tag.name }}
   <img src="{{ rand_img.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Same result, I lose the attributes :S